# What is the old AIX & RS/6000 console font?

Tags: fonts, console, aix

I'm sick of Lucida Console font on my putty sessions.  I used to love whatever font was employed on IBM rs/6000 consoles.  Does anyone know the name of that font and if it is available (and usable) from anywhere?

---

Sorry, I need to clarify the "consoles" to which I refer were not the serial consoles but rather smaller stand-alone X-Window systems.  They could be setup without XDM and would start in text screen.  I'm searching like crazy to find the actual machines I remember (there were hundreds of them at Uni) but I don't have the IBM #s in front of me.

It looked amazingly similar to the PS/2 like this:

[image]

Comment: Which 'old' rs6000 console?  Ths 3151 or 3153?  You are talking about the serial consoles?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: I also desperately want this font. Back in the day when I had access to RS6K machines I copied the XWindows version of that font and used it on my Linux box, but that was ~15 years ago.  All I remember is that it had "Roman" in the name.

Comment: I renewed the search for this font recently and found this one which is pretty close http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Roman+Fixed-width/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I don't ever remember knowing if there was a name for the console font for the old pSeries.  The ps/2 beige box you're thinking of is likely the 7012-36T or similar model.  I remember having a black 43p a while back.

I know if you do a Google image search for `smitty aix console` you'll find images of the font, but I can't think of any current font that matches it.

Jeff Atwood had a [blog article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000969.html) of programming fonts, including his link to an article about [clear type](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000651.html).

He presents a link to [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html).

Another [blog article](http://keithdevens.com/wiki/ProgrammerFonts) on programming fonts.

Comment: Yes, the 7012s may be it, thought they're a little bigger.  I found the following http://www.pospischil.co.at/pic/rs6000.jpg which more matches.  Not relevant to the font question though?  Looking for some nostalgia I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I myself have wondered the same thing. I have a reasonably close solution though... I find that the "MS Mincho" font (google it) somewhat resembles that old rs6000 console font. I don't remember the model I was working on, but it was around 1991 or 1992, so, really ancient. :)